# helm trouble creating pod using bitnami/mongodb chart

Tags: kubernetes, helm, kubernetes-helm

Here is my `My Chart.yaml` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: pixer-microservice-infra
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
dependencies:
  - name: mongodb
    version: ~14.3.1
    repository: "@bitnami"
    alias: mongodb
```

After running commands:

```
helm dependency build .
helm upgrade <chart-name>
```

my mongodb pod has the status: CrashLoopBackOff

Checked pod logs: `kubectl logs pod/<pod-name>`

`/opt/bitnami/scripts/libos.sh: line 346:   154 Illegal instruction     "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1`

`uname -m`: arm64

Is there any compatible issue between this chart and the CPU architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mongodb 5 on x86 requires a cpu with avx, check your cpu flags of the kubernetes node with lscpu | grep avx

Comment: mongodb should check that and emit a proper error